# AWS Cognito Lambda Trigger user attributes example

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm creating a tiny API using Cognito & Lambda. I would like to use the Cognito Lambda trigger to do some stuff when new users register (via Facebook) and when user loges in.

I've googled a lot and of course followed [Amazon's guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-auth) but I couldn't find any examples regarding the "*userAttributes*" dictionary.

Can someone provide an example for this triggers?

Comment: So are you just interested in knowing what's in the `userAttributes` dictionary?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm just interested what's in there and if I can use this information to identify the user and take action. Also I'd like to know if there are differences between the `userAttributes` of the different triggers, especially _preSignUp_ and _postAuthentification_ (I hope that _postAuthentification_ is the one after LogIn).

Comment: Have you tried writing a lambda and printing out those event values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userAttributes` dictionary contains the available attributes like Name, email, phone number etc. The actual attribute available is determined by the attribute read permissions set for your app client & in case of external providers like Facebook, the attribute mapping defined in the Userpool. As @Kannaiyan said, the best way to learn about these values would be to print them in your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details of values that are needed for userAttributes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-user-migration

> userAttributes This field is required.
>
> It must contain one or more name-value pairs representing user
>   attributes to be stored in the user profile in your user pool. You can
>   include both standard and custom user attributes. Custom attributes
>   require the custom: prefix to distinguish them from standard
>   attributes. For more information see Custom attributes.
>
> Note
>
> In order for users to reset their passwords in the forgot-password
>   flow, they must have either a verified email or a verified phone
>   number. Amazon Cognito sends a message containing a reset password
>   code to the email or phone number in the user attributes.
>
> Attributes    Requirement Any attributes marked as required when you
>   created your user pool    If any required attributes are missing during
>   the migration, default values will be used. username   Required if you
>   have configured your user pool with email and/or preferred_username
>   aliases in addition to username for sign-in, and the user has entered
>   an email or phone number to sign-in.
>
> Otherwise, it is optional and will be used as the username instead of
>   the username entered by the user.
>
> Note
>
> username must be unique in the user pool.
>
> cognito:mfa_enabled   Required if MFA is configured as optional in the
>   User Pool. This attribute specifies whether MFA is enabled for the
>   user.